# Как можно найти букву USB

Tags: usb

Как можно найти букву *USB* при загрузке собственной программы?

Если можно, примерчик.

Comment: Уточните язык и операционную систему.

Comment: Букву USB?

Comment: видимо имеется ввиду flash drive.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, не так уж много операционных систем с буквами дисков ;)

Answer (score 5):

Я рискну расшифровать этот загадочный вопрос так: как определить, каким «буквам» — то есть именам томов — в Windows какие носители соответствуют; и конкретно, определить носители типа USB-drive.

Тогда в помощь функции:

- [GetDriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364939%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() для «грубого» определения, и
- [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() для точного определения флагов CM_REMOVAL_POLICY_EXPECT

Примеры:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264203/en
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305184/en